# Can't reach Asp.Net Core inside Docker

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docker

I have a Asp.Net core MVC application running inside a Docker Container, but I can't reach it from localhost, Any thoughts?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:runtime
ARG source=publish/

WORKDIR /usr/src/project

COPY $source .

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","project.dll"]
```

And the run command:

```
docker run -t the/image . -p 5000:5000
```

And I get the message

> Now listening on: http://*:5000

But I still can't access it through `localhost:5000` or `192.168.99.100:5000`

Comment: Can you confirm the run command? Everything after the image name will be passed as an argument to the container, so you need to put the `-p` earlier: `docker run -p 5000:5000 the/image`

Comment: That's it, I don't know why I didn't see it, could you post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything after the image name will be passed as an argument to the container, so you need to put the `-p` earlier. Try:

`docker run -p 5000:5000 the/image`